# Are Numpy arrays hashable?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, immutability, numpy-ndarray

I've read that numpy arrays are hashable which means it is immutable but I'm able to change it's values so what does it exactly mean by being hashable?

```
c=pd.Series('a',index=range(6))
c
Out[276]: 
0    a
1    a
2    a
3    a
4    a
5    a
dtype: object
```

This doesn't give me error then why it gives error if I try to do the same with numpy array.

```
d=pd.Series(np.array(['a']),index=range(6))
```

Comment: "I've read that numpy arrays are hashable" where have you read this?

Comment: `c` fills all elements with the scalar string value.  What's the error for `d`?  That has significant information.

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to what you have read, **array are not hashable**. You can test this with

```
import numpy as np,collections
isinstance(np.array(1), collections.Hashable)
```

or

```
{np.array(1):1}
```

This has nothing to do with the error you are getting:

```
d=pd.Series(np.array('a'),index=range(6))
ValueError: Wrong number of dimensions
```

the error is specific, and has nothing to do with hashes. The data frame is expecting at least something with 1 dimension, whereas the above has 0 dimensions. This is due to the fact it is getting an array - so it checks the dimension (as opposed to passing the string directly, where Pandas developers have chosen to implement as you have shown. TBH they could have chosen the same for a 0 dimension array).

So you could try:

```
d=pd.Series(np.array(('a',)),index=range(6))
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 6
```

The index value expects there to be a 6 in one dimension, so it fails. Finally

```
pd.Series(np.array(['a']*6),index=range(6))
0    a
1    a
2    a
3    a
4    a
5    a
dtype: object
```

works. So the DataFrame has no problem being initiated from an array, and this has nothing to do with hashability.